# Livewire Dependent Dropdown

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have three DB tables `Users`, `Divisions` and `Subdivisions`. `Division` has many `Subdivisions`.

One `User` must have `division_id` and can have `subdivision_id` (column is nullable).

On `User` update page I have form with two dependent selects: `Select division` and `Select subdivision`. These selects must fill with data from `Users` table.

`Division` select working well. `Subdivision` dependent select work only when I mount all `Subdivions`:

```
public function updated()
{
    $this->subdivisions = Subdivision::query()
                          ->select("id", "name")
                          ->where('division_id', '=', $this->division_id)
                          ->get();
}

public function mount()
{
    $this->divisions = Division::all();
    $this->subdivisions = Subdivision::all();
}
```

When I commented one line `Subdivision` dependent select don't work.  If I leaving subdivisions empty, I can't set any user. But when I fill all subdivisions on mount my code works, but user can see all subdivisions, not only from his division.

```
public function updated()
{
    $this->subdivisions = Subdivision::query()
                          ->select("id", "name")
                          ->where('division_id', '=', $this->division_id)
                          ->get();
}

public function mount()
{
    $this->divisions = Division::all();
    //$this->subdivisions = Subdivision::all();
}
```

[image: Example: Set User 3]

[image: Image with relations]

Test repository: https://github.com/OlyaK95/livewire-dependent-dropdown

1. Run `git clone https://github.com/OlyaK95/livewire-dependent-dropdown.git`
2. Run `cd livewire-dependent-dropdown`
3. Run `composer install`
4. Run `cp .env.example .env`
5. Run `php artisan key:generate`
6. Run `npm install && npm run dev`
7. Run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`
8. Run `php artisan serve`
9. Go to link `localhost:8000`

Comment: `When I commented one line`...well obviously if you comment out the line which populates that dropdown then it won't have any data. So what? But I don't see anything where you've attempted to make the second dropdown dependent on the first. Have you actually tried to do that?

Comment: @ADyson Of course, yes. What about to check my code https://github.com/OlyaK95/livewire-dependent-dropdown/blob/main/app/Livewire/DependentDropdown.php ?

Comment: @ADyson My question about how to prepopulate subdivisions, when I don't know `division_id`. And what can I do when I change `division_id`, because subdivision don't change.

Comment: If you have relevant code to show us, you need to share it _here_ in your question. See [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. Linking to another site (which may change, or may no longer exist in future, or may contain lots of other irrelevant info) is not accepted by the stackoverflow community - because if that info changes or disappears then it makes your post a lot less useful for future readers. Please edit your question. Thankyou.

Comment: `My question about how to prepopulate subdivisions, when I don't know division_id`...well, how about leaving it empty? But from your screenshot, it does look like you should know the initial Division value (at the very least, it would be the first item returned by Division::all(), surely?)

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I edited my question. If I leaving subdivisions empty, I can't set any user. But when I fill all subdivisions on mount my code works, but user can see all subdivisions, not only from his division.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+livewire+dependent+dropdown - surely you can copy one of the many examples already available online and adapt it to your situation

Comment: @ADyson You are so smart. I forgot about Google. Are you kidding me?

Comment: Well, actually no I'm not. Do we really need to repeat ourselves or make a new example of this technique? What's wrong with all the existing information about this topic? What have you tried? What didn't work? How is your situation different? Why should we spend the time to start again from scratch?

Comment: @ADyson Good example of edit page https://github.com/tapan288/livewire-dependent-dropdown/blob/master/app/Http/Livewire/Student/Edit.php At this example `Classes` = `Divisions`, `Sections` = `Subdivisions`. But this example not suitable to me, because I can't fill `Sections` on `mount()`. I have buttons to set `User`.

Comment: Why can't you? If you define a default value for the Division field, then you can. As I said, even if there isn't a prefined value before runtime, you could just use the first value returned from the list of Divisions in the database, as the default

Comment: @ADyson I have very little code here https://github.com/OlyaK95/livewire-dependent-dropdown/blob/main/app/Livewire/DependentDropdown.php I think you can understand all lines. My code WORK 100% when I click on selects. BUT. When I set some User code WORK SOMETIMES, only If next User have the same Division. How can explain it? Maybe I need some Google again?